# Play Framework -- how to access development server from another machine

Tags: playframework

I need to do some cross browser testing on a play framework app and am trying to figure out how to serve it to a different machine.

I've been working with Django a lot lately. When starting the Django development server, I need to pass my IP address as an argument in order to allow other machines in, like so:

`python manage runserver 192.168.1.141:8000`

Is there an equivalent command for the play framework development server?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the normal command line [args](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ProductionConfiguration) for production also work for development:

```
$ sbt start -Dhttp.port=1234 -Dhttp.address=127.0.0.1
```